# Error occured when migrate mysql in django

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django

I installed mysql client -- pip install mysqlclient
but when i made connection to mysql using this code

```
    'default': {
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
      'NAME': 'django_db',
      'USER' : 'root',
      'PASSWORD' : '',
      'HOST' : '127.0.0.1',
      'PORT' : '8080'
 }
```

following error returns :
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0")

Answer (score 0):

This is because django couldn't connect to mysql database.

Try changing host to 'localhost', its still the same but might work.

Also check your mysql port when you run mysql on your computer.